# What version of Internet Explorer should I install?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a Dell Inspiron 530 computer - 7 years old but still works fine, dual core, running Windows Vista Home Premium, 32 bit, service pack 1 & 2 are both installed. I'm using Internet Explorer 8 which is fine except that more and more programs I like won't support 8. 
I've been told that IE9 won't run with this version of vista.
Which newer version of Internet Explorer should I install?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft says you can install IE 9 on Vista SP2

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-system-requirements#ie=ie-9